# Repetição de select

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um formulário e no campo origem, o usuário deve escolher um dos 5 destinos disponíveis. Quando ele selecionar, o campo destino deve abrir outros 4 options com os destinos disponíveis para a origem (que devem ser todos os outros, menos o da origem), que foram inseridos através do JavaScript.

Da primeira vez que a origem é selecionada, o destino aparece sem problemas, mas caso o usuário mude a origem ou o destino, os options do destino se repetem -inclusive é possível selecionar destino e origens iguais -, e isso acontece cada vez que a origem ou o destino são mudados. Como evitar essa repetição?

Segue o código:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title> Agência de Viagens </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function funcorigem()
    {
    origem=window.document.ftaxi.origem.value;
    destino=window.document.ftaxi.destino;  
        if(origem=="rj")
        {
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text=" ";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="São Paulo";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Belo Horizonte";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Salvador";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Santa Catarina";
                destino.add(option);

            }
    if(origem=="sp")
    {
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text=" ";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Rio de Janeiro";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Belo Horizonte";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Salvador";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Santa Catarina";
                destino.add(option);

    }
    if(origem=="bh")
    {
            option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text=" ";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Rio de Janeiro";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="São Paulo";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Salvador";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Santa Catarina";
                destino.add(option);
    }
    if(origem=="sc")
    {

                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text=" ";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Rio de Janeiro";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="São Paulo";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Belo Horizonte";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Salvador";
                destino.add(option);
    }
if(origem=="salv")
    {

                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text=" ";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Rio de Janeiro";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="São Paulo";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Belo Horizonte";
                destino.add(option);
                option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text="Santa Catarina";
                destino.add(option);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="ftaxi">
Origem: &nbsp;<select name="origem" onchange="funcorigem()">
<option value=" "> Escolha </option>
<option value="rj"> Rio de Janeiro </option>
<option value="sp"> São Paulo </option>
<option value="bh"> Belo Horizonte </option>
<option value="sc"> Santa Cantarina </option> 
<option value="salv"> Salvador </option> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</select><p>
Data:&nbsp;<input type="date" name="data">&nbsp;&nbsp; <p>
Hora: &nbsp;<input type="text" size="8" maxlength="7"><p>
Destino:&nbsp;<select name="destino" onchange="funcorigem()"></select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Me desculpem se algo parecido já tenha sido perguntado antes, mas não encontrei nenhum tópico que pudesse me ajudar. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve esvaziar o select antes de adicionar novos options para evitar a repetição.

Coloque `destino.innerHTML = '';` após a linha `destino=window.document.ftaxi.destino;`:

```
function funcorigem(){
   origem=window.document.ftaxi.origem.value;
   destino=window.document.ftaxi.destino; 
   destino.innerHTML = ''; // esvazia o elemento
   // resto do código
```

Comment: Tentei. Os options não se repetem mais, mas tive outro problema: não consigo selecioná-los. Mesmo que eu clique para escolher um, o campo destino não fica preenchido com o selecionado, continuando em branco.

Comment: Isso acontece por causa do `onchange="funcorigem()"` no select do destino. Retire-o.

Comment: Resolveu, muito obrigada pela ajuda!